# Configure ASP.NET Application to Read Mapped Network Drive

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

Is it possible to configure an ASP.NET application under IIS 7 so it can read files stored in a mapped network drive? I'm not trying to serve up the contents of the drive. I simply need to read the contents within the ASP.NET application. I've searched the Web and haven't really found a solid answer. The questions in my mind are:

1. Is this possible via configuration (i.e. I cannot modify the client code)?
2. If so, what are the step by step instructions.

If it is not possible, I'm fine with that. I already know UNC paths work but using them drastically changes the work flow.

Thanks!

Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of - because mapped drives blong to a session. You COULD try spawning the net use command cfrom th aspnet ap and see what happens.

I would go with UNC paths.

Comment: I would go with UNC paths. - what do you mean?  So how would you setup IIS to use UNC?

Comment: You dont. You just use a UNC path in the stream open command.